# Calling my function I passed through as a parameter

Tags: c#, delegates

I have a function:

```
public void Callback()
{
    // Does some stuff
}
```

I want to pass that in to another function, which then passes it to another function, which then executes the function... I have this so far:

```
public void StartApp() // entry point
{
    StartMyAwesomeAsyncPostRequest( Callback );
}

public void StartMyAwesomeAsyncPostRequest( Delegate callback )
{
    // Work out some stuff and start a post request
    TheActualAsyncPostRequest( callback );
}

public void TheActualAsyncPostRequest( Delegate callback )
{
    // Do some jazz then run the delegated function
    callback();
}
```

I have looked through a few other examples but coming from a PHP and javascript background, I'm struggling with the explanations, can you perhaps give me an example or explanation specific to my request? Thanks in advance!

Comment: So what issue are you encountering that produces unexpected results? I'm not sure exactly what you're asking to be solved.

Comment: Beyond the fact that there's nothing inherently "async" about the code you've posted, I'm not sure it's clear what you're struggling with. Can you explain?

Comment: Well the syntax is wrong, it doesn't work. I can't do Callback(), it just fails. so how do I call the function I've passed all the way through?

Answer (score 7):

Try declaring the parameter type as a particular *kind* of delegate. In this case, since your callback doesn't accept any argument and doesn't return any results, use an [`Action`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action.aspx):

```
public void StartMyAwesomeAsyncPostRequest(Action callback)
{
    TheActualAsyncPostRequest(callback);
}

public void TheActualAsyncPostRequest(Action callback)
{
    callback();
}
```

If you wanted to be able to pass an argument to the callback, use an [`Action<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx) (or one of its many cousins, to pass more than one argument):

```
public void StartMyAwesomeAsyncPostRequest(Action<string> callback)
{
    TheActualAsyncPostRequest(callback);
}

public void TheActualAsyncPostRequest(Action<string> callback)
{
    callback("Foo");
}
```

Or to get a result from the callback, use a [`Func<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx) (or one of its many cousins, to pass in any arguments):

```
public void StartMyAwesomeAsyncPostRequest(Func<string> callback)
{
    TheActualAsyncPostRequest(callback);
}

public void TheActualAsyncPostRequest(Func<string> callback)
{
    string result = callback();
}
```

Comment: Gosh, thanks, that works much better :D That has allowed me to do Callback(), now i'm happy :)

Comment: Your extra edits just answered my next question, thank you so so much!